# Facebook messenger app webhook subscription - Insufficient Permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-webhooks

I have facebook messenger application (it is bot using MS Bot Framework, although I don't think it is relevant). It has webhook subscribed to page events. It used to work fine until few days ago, when the webhook was unsubscribed from page and when I am trying to subscribe again it tells me:

> "Insufficient Permission You do not have the necessary permission for
>   the specified Page to perform the requested action."

I am owner and admin on both the FB page and messenger app. I created similar page and messenger app and it works there, but I still need to use this old one. I tried subscribing to other pages which I own and admin, but with same result. I also tried it with other person who is admin.

I found other people experiencing same/similar message on FB, but not in this particular case. But I haven't found any solution.

Does anyone know what could be the problem? Or have anyone experienced this issue?

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to generate a token first. Under messager->Settings->Token Generation-> Select your page and you'll be prompted to give the permission. Grant all permission required, then you shall be able to subscribe or unsubscribe to pages you manage.

This process gives your application the token to validate if you have the moderator or higher rights to the page you want to subscribe to.

Comment: What if I already have a the Page Access Token, but it still won't let me access / subscribe to the page?

Answer (score 7):

After spending 3 days on this. Here is the solution for this.

1. Go to your Facebook Profile - > Settings -> Apps
   and Remove YOUR APP from there.
2. In Developer Dashboard Go to App Review -> Add Items

   1. manage_pages
      (This Permission Needed for Accessing page access tokens)

   Add above permission for review - with any simple video of above error
3. Now go to Messanger-> Settings -> Token Generation
   Select page from dropdown List 
   now it will open a popup (because you removed this app in 1st step) for app access permission , notice that now it will ask for manage pages permission
   Grant those permission and create access tokens
4. Now try again subscribing Webhook to Pages

   This Works for me.

Comment: I feel your pain spending 3 days on this man :) thanks for the answer - it solved problem for me as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate your page access token for this.
Go to your facebook Developer dashboard, and open the messenger tab. There, you will see this for token generation. Select your page and generate the token. Then use this token in your bot.
[Page access token generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6fO4.png)